# Инверсия порядка элементов в массиве

Tags: c#

> Дан массив размера N. Поменять порядок его элементов на обратный.

Как надо решить? Как начать?

Comment: Задачу на массив оформить с помощью лямда выражений. Элементы массива получить с помощью Random

Answer (score 7, accepted):

самый простой вариант - воспользоватся встроеной функцией реверса:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    a.Reverse();//вернёт массив в обратном порядке
}
```

второй - написать реверс самому:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Reverse(int[] array)
{
    for(int i = array.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        yield return array[i];
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое)вы мне очень помогли

Comment: лучшая благодарность - отметка правильного ответа

Comment: yield return вот это не поняла(
и это все что ли?

Comment: ключевое слово ``[yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dscyy5s0.aspx)`` означает, что функция не прекратит своё выполнение после ``return``, т.е. некоторое значение вернётся, но функция продолжит свою работу с места возврата значения.

Comment: Просто и изящно.Респект.

Comment: Это только пишется просто, в работе, это разворачивается в бо'льшую конструкцию...

Если верно понял, то массив не копировался -> поэтому результат функции - нельзя считать корректным...

Comment: приведите пример ситуации, когда результат будем некорректным

Comment: когда исходный массив изменился....

Comment: Так и думал, что у подобных штучек могут быть плохо предсказываемые побочные эффекты.

Comment: о чём вы? это функция и возвращаемое ею значение никак не изменятся из-за изменений исходного массива, аргумент функции передаётся по значению, а не по ссылке, вы глубоко заблуждаетесь, утверждая подобное! если вы изменили массив и вам нужен его реверсивный вариант, будьте добры, вызовите функцию ещё раз, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 6):

Самый простой и эффективный вариант этого алгоритма (назависимо от C#, C, Pascal, Java, Basic ...) в цикле менять значения первого с последним, второго с предпоследним и т.д.

Т.е. для массива a[] длиной n :

```
for (i = 0, j = n-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    t = a[i]; 
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
}
```

Не понимаю, почему этому не учат на лекциях, семинарах ...

Comment: Я думаю учат ) А если массив не чётный? ) Это подводный камень для этого алгоритма.

Comment: никакой это не камень. цикл дойдет до серединного элемента и прекратится.

Comment: В дополнение - Средний элемент-жеж не надо перемещать...

Comment: угу. именно.

Comment: стоит проверить, точно уже не помню, как раз дело в том что средний не сравнивается ни с каким элементом, всё строится вокруг него.надо проверить )

Comment: По определению средний элемент это i == j. Условие продолжения цикла это i < j. 

"Из чего со всей очевидностью следует", лишнего обмена не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант это объявить новую переменную в которой будет храниться полученный массив, и в цикле который будет идти от максимального до минимального элементов в исходном массиве заполнить его. Т. е. примерно так:

```
int [] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // исходный массив
int [] b; // желаемый массив
int j = 0;
for( int i = a.sizeof(); i = 0; i-- )
{
    b[j] = a[i];
    j++;
}
```

Comment: у вас ошибок в коде много